# Why my python version hoare partition quick sort is slower than lomuto partition?

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort

Normally when implementing quick sort, Hoare's scheme is more efficient than Lomuto's partition scheme because of fewer swaps on average. To verify this, I try to count the swaps in all possible permutations with repeated elements. I generate a list of all possible repeatable permutations of 8 elements to test, totally 8 to the power of 8 permutations. But the result on my machine is strange, Hoare's scheme is slower even it has fewer swaps. Here is the python codes:

```
import copy
import time

swap_lomuto = 0
swap_hoare = 0

def hoare_partition(a, p, r):
    global swap_hoare
    pivot = a[(p+r)//2]
    i = p - 1
    j = r + 1
    while True:
        i = i + 1
        j = j - 1
        while a[i] < pivot:
            i = i + 1
        while a[j] > pivot:
            j = j - 1
        if i < j:
            a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
            swap_hoare += 1
        else:
            return j

def quick_sort_hoare(a, lo, hi):
    if lo < hi:
        p = hoare_partition(a, lo, hi)
        quick_sort_hoare(a, lo, p)
        quick_sort_hoare(a, p+1, hi)


def lomuto_partition(a, p, r):
    global swap_lomuto
    pivot = a[r]
    i = j = p
    while j < r:
        if a[j] < pivot:
            a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
            i = i + 1
            swap_lomuto += 1
        j = j + 1
    a[i], a[r] = a[r], a[i]
    swap_lomuto +=1
    return i

def quick_sort_lomuto(a, lo, hi):
    if lo < hi:
        p = lomuto_partition(a, lo, hi)
        quick_sort_lomuto(a, lo, p-1)
        quick_sort_lomuto(a, p+1, hi)

def gen_cases(n):
    a = list(range(1, n+1))
    r = [[]]
    def product(A, B):
        result = []
        for a in A:
            for b in B:
                result.append(a + [b])
        return result
    for i in range(n):
        r = product(r, a)
    return r

# generate 8**8 permutations with repeated elements
# e.g. [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2]] when n == 2
n = 8
cases1 = gen_cases(n)
cases2 = copy.deepcopy(cases1)

start = time.time()
for c in cases1:
    quick_sort_lomuto(c, 0, len(c)-1)
end = time.time()
print("lomuto time: ", end-start)
print("lomuto swaps: ", swap_lomuto)

start = time.time()
for c in cases2:
    quick_sort_hoare(c, 0, len(c)-1)
end = time.time()
print("hoare time: ", end-start)
print("hoare swaps: ", swap_hoare)

# assert if two methods give the same result
for i in range(len(cases1)):
    for j in range(n):
        assert cases1[i][j] == cases2[i][j]
```

The result on my machine is

lomuto time:  46.35845708847046
lomuto swaps:  199594736
hoare time:  59.4106240272522
hoare swaps:  116165488

I can't figure out where is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

See if this version does any better. This may be an issue where the interpreter overhead has a greater effect then the algorithm efficiency.

If sorting random or pseudo random numbers, I've found Lomuto to be slightly faster than Hoare.

```
def qsort(a, lo, hi):
    if(lo >= hi):
        return
    p = a[(lo + hi) // 2]       # pivot, any a[] except a[hi]
    i = lo - 1
    j = hi + 1
    while(1):
        while(1):               # while(a[++i] < p)
            i += 1
            if(a[i] >= p):
                break
        while(1):               # while(a[--j] < p)
            j -= 1
            if(a[j] <= p):
                break
        if(i >= j):
            break
        a[i],a[j] = a[j],a[i]
    qsort(a, lo, j)
    qsort(a, j+1, hi)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This version is still slower than lomuto version although its swaps is fewer. The running time of this version on the same test cases is around 52-55 seconds, with 116165488 swaps. Seems function calls isn't the main issue.

Comment: @abzie - I got similar results using compiled C++. Sorting 16 million 64 bit unsigned pseudo random integers, takes about 1.34 seconds with Lomuto, 1.38 seconds with Hoare. Although Hoare does fewer swaps, apparently it's reading more data, partially due to the fact that the pivot is not excluded from recursive calls. Hoare handles duplicate elements better though.